# Ruby methods similar to attr_reader

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to make a method similar to `attr_reader` but I can't seem to get the instance of the class that the method gets called in.

```
class Module
  def modifiable_reader(*symbols)
    # Right here is where it returns Klass instead of #<Klass:0x1df25e0 @readable="this">
    mod = self

    variables = symbols.collect { |sym| ("@" << sym.to_s).to_sym }
    attr_reader *symbols

    (class << ModifyMethods; self; end).instance_eval do
      define_method(*symbols) do
        mod.instance_variable_get(*variables)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Object
  module ModifyMethods; end
  def modify(&block)
    ModifyMethods.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

```
class Klass
  modifiable_reader :readable

  def initialize
    @readable = "this"
  end
end

my_klass = Klass.new
my_klass.modify do
  puts "Readable: " << readable.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do.

If it helps, the spell for attr_reader is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

module Kernel

  def my_attr_reader(symbol)
    eval <<-EOS
      def #{symbol}
        @#{symbol}
      end
    EOS
  end

end

class Foo

  my_attr_reader :foo

  def initialize
    @foo = 'foo'
  end

end

p Foo.new.foo     # => "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can understand from your code is that you want to have the `modify` block to respond to the instance methods of `Klass`, that's as simple as:

```
class Klass
  attr_reader :modifiable
  alias_method :modify, :instance_eval

  def initialize(m)
    @modifiable = m
  end

end

Klass.new('john').modify do
  puts 'Readable %s' % modifiable
end
```

About this tidbit of code:

```
def modifiable_reader(*symbols)
  # Right here is where it returns Klass instead of #<Klass:0x1df25e0 @readable="this">
  mod = self
  ...
```

Probably this can give you a hint of what is going on:

```
Class.superclass # => Module
Klass.instance_of?(Class) # => true

Klass = Class.new do 
  def hello
    'hello'
  end
end
Klass.new.hello # => 'hello'
```

When you are adding methods to the `Module` class, you are also adding methods to the `Class` class, which will add  an instance method to instances of `Class` (in this case your class `Klass`), at the end this means you are adding class methods on your `Klass` class